# How to dereference pointer to a class instance?

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-7, dereference

**Problem abstract:** I point a pointer to a class instance, but, when I try to dereference this pointer and access the properties of the instance, I get an EAccessViolation exception because it dereferences to "Nil".

I declare the pointer in the unit scope:

```
private
  CurrentRXFrame: ^TSXcpFrame;
```

Every time my program receives a frame, the pointer is updated to point to this latest frame:

```
procedure TfrmFoo.OnReceivingFrame(Sender: TObject);
var
  SXcpFrame: TSXcpFrame;
begin
  SXcpFrame := TSXcpFrame.Create();
  CurrentRXFrame := @SXcpFrame;
```

I try to dereference the pointer in some other routine in the same unit, but get an exception:

```
// `FrameBytes` is merely a dynamic array of type "Byte".
PrintMsg(IntToHex(CurrentRXFrame^.FrameBytes[0], 2));
```

The exception:

`raise exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 004DD1FE [...] Read of address 00000010.`

If I set a breakpoint right before this line here is what the relevant vars evaluate to:

```
CurrentRXFrame := $18FD10
CurrentRXFrame^ := nil
CurrentRXFrame^.FrameBytes := Inaccessible value
```

**Question:** How do I access the properties of an instance of class `TSxcpFrame` through a pointer?

Comment: You took the address of a local variable. That address is valid until the end of the function that declared the variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have a pointer to the variable, and if that is a local variable, it gets invalid very quickly.

But there is no need for that. **Class instance refrences are already pointers**, so you could (or, IMO, should) do:

```
var
  CurrentRXFrame: TSXcpFrame;
```

and later on:

```
  SXcpFrame := TSXcpFame.Create;
  CurrentRXFrame := SXcpFrame;
```

and of course:

```
  PrintMsg(IntToHex(CurrentRXFrame.FrameBytes[0], 2));
```

Note that `SXcpFrame` and `CurrentRXFrame` are not structures, they are merely references to one, so on assignment, no copy of the data is made, only of the reference. The structure of the instance with the data lives on the heap. After the assignment, both references refer to the same data.

Comment: Bravo, sir! That works. Thank you very much. The point about variables, which hold instances, already being pointers is a very important thing to know.

Comment: I recommend reading the [Delphi Language Guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Delphi_Language_Guide_Index), which is part of the built-in help, but it can be found online too.

Comment: That link is for XE7, not Delphi 7. The built-in help is only good as a reference. I also have the "Object Pascal Language Guide" document, but I found nothing there (or anywhere on the web) about pointers to class instances.

Comment: Ok, I found the D7LG. In the chapter "Classes and Objects", section "Class Types" it says: "A variable of a class type is actually a pointer that references an object. Hence more than one variable can refer to the same object. Like other pointers, class-type variables can hold the value nil. But you don't have to explicitly dereference a class-type variable to access the object it points to."

Comment: The XE7 language guide is fine for D7. There are few changes. And all versions of the language guide describe this issue clearly. The language guide is very well written. I commend it to you.